PyQt6: QMediaPlayer producing no sound, or an error
class AudioWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, file_path, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.file_path = file_path

        self.setFixedSize(250, 50)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WidgetAttribute.WA_StyledBackground, True)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: #6a5a8a;")
        self.play_button = QPushButton("Play", self)
        self.play_button.clicked.connect(self.toggle_audio)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.play_button)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        
        self.audio_player = QMediaPlayer()
        self.audio_playing = False

    def toggle_audio(self):
        if not self.audio_playing:
            self.audio_player.setSource(QUrl.fromLocalFile(self.file_path))
            self.audio_player.play()
            self.play_button.setText("Stop")
            self.audio_playing = True
        else:
            self.audio_player.stop()
            self.play_button.setText("Play")
            self.audio_playing = False

Here's a stripping down form of my AudioWidget class. Any time I open an audio file and attempt to play it, it either does nothing, or I get:
[mp3 @ 0x7fe668012100] Format mp3 detected only with low score of 1, misdetection possible!
[mp3float @ 0x7fe66800d680] Header missing
[mp3 @ 0x7fe668012100] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Audio: mp3 (mp3float), 0 channels, fltp): unspecified frame size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
qt.multimedia.ffmpeg.mediadataholder: AVStream duration -9223372036854775808 is invalid. Taking it from the metadata

(Using Ubuntu)
QMediaPlayer isn't playing audio.

as for me file can be broken. Error shows Header missing. Did you try with other file formats? ogg, wav? Did you try to run this mp3 in other player?

@furas yeah I realize that file was broken - all other files load fine, just produce no sound

maybe problem is in different place, Maybe it needs some drivers in system. Or maybe in program or in system it needs to set volume. Or maybe it needs to use other audio driver. I use Linux Mint based on Ubuntu and sometimes I don't have sound and I have to kill pulseaudio

I've not played around with QMediaPlayer in Qt6, but as far as I know, and as opposed to Qt5, you need to explicitly set a QAudioOutput: self.audioOutput = QAudioOutput() self.audio_player.setAudioOutput(self.audioOutput) (making it an instance attribute may not be necessary, but it's probably safer, as the documentation doesn't mention if it needs to remain alive or if the player takes ownership).

Please don't edit a question to add the solution. You should normally add an answer instead (using the dedicated button) but in this case it isn't necessary anymore, as I found a similar question that makes yours a relatively similar duplicate. Note that my intuition above turned out to be correct, and the QAudioOutput instance must be persistent, so either do what already suggested, or eventually create the instance with a parent object (which could be the media player or the top level window), for example: self.audio_player.setAudioOutput(QAudioOutput(self)).
